# Get Video Title in BigQuery

Tags: youtube, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, google-bigquery

I did a data transfer of a youtube channel into BigQuery. Videos are identified by their video ID, not title. Is there a way to get the title table so I can join it to the IDs? Or do I need to work with the YT API in a second step after BQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, only the video id is provided through the channel report. As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/youtube-channel-transfer#setting_up_a_youtube_channel_transfer):

> The BigQuery Data Transfer Service for YouTube Channel reports
>   currently supports the following reporting options:
>
> - Channel Reports (automatically loaded into BigQuery

[Channel reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports) via the YouTube API don't include the title. You'll need to call the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#id) directly (outside of BigQuery) to get a mapping of video id to video title. Then upload that as a table in BigQuery. Then you can join on it to get the title in your BigQuery reports.

Comment: Hi @Graham - Can you please give more details, how can we accomplish call to youtube API outside BigQuery?